# Error while trying to run shell script using OS process sampler in jmeter

Tags: shell, testing, jmeter

one.jmx file takes command line arguments so i am putting the long command to run one.jmx in a shell script(RUN_GET_CALLS.sh). Now i am using Two.jmx which calls One.jmx via the shell script using OS process sampler.
When i execute Two.jmx it is giving error

```js
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1548833794770,4,"Patient_""_id""",500,"Exception occurred whilst executing system call: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""bash /home/ubuntu/HSDP_Suit/TestSuite/JMX_files/RUN_GET_CALLS.sh"" (in directory ""/home/ubuntu/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin""): error=2, No such file or directory",Patient 1-4,text,false,,0,0,6,6,null,0,0,0
```

[image]

I tried putting path in Working directory box also but it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is a little bit incorrect you should configure the [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) as follows:

- Command: `/bin/bash`
- Working directory: `/home/ubuntu/HSDP_Suit/TestSuite/JMX_files`
- Argument #1: `-c`
- Argument #2: `./RUN_GET_CALLS.sh ${PROPERTY_FILE} ${RESOURCE} ${PARAMETERS_STRING} ${FILE_NAME} ${RESULT_FILE}`

Example configuration screenshot:

[image]

As per [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> **-c** string
>
> If the **-c** option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with **$0**.

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: 1548838036196,41,"Patient_""_has:Observation:patient:code""",2,OK,Patient 1-2,text,true,,433,0,6,6,null,0,0,0                                        This is the response inside jtl file after i change the script. which means it is not executing any command

Comment: I am not telepathic enough to guess what your `RUN_GET_CALLS.sh` doing, check  request and response data tabs of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see what's going on there

Comment: Oh my mistake, the it is able to run the shell script. Thank you for the answer